# 03-23 01:34:35.861: E/AndroidRuntime(613): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "in": syntax error: , while compiling:

Tags: database

Im just starting to learn how to create and use a database.
Here is the error I get:03-23 01:34:35.861: E/AndroidRuntime(613): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "in": syntax error: , while compiling: create table payouts(_id integer primary key autoincrement, date text not null, casino text not null, game text not null, in text not null, out text not null, gain text not null);

I have gone over it, and I cant seem to figure out why it will not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

```
    package kris.databasetester;    
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_CASINO = "casino";   
public static final String KEY_GAME = "game";   
public static final String KEY_IN = "in";   
public static final String KEY_OUT = "out"; 
public static final String KEY_GAIN = "gain";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "casinodb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "payouts";
private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table payouts(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "date text not null, casino text not null, " + "game text not null, in text not null, out text not null, gain text not null);";
//  private static final String date = null;

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}  //DBAdapter Closer
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    } //onCreate Closer
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destory all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payouts");
        onCreate(db);
    } //onUpgrade Closer
} //DatabaseHelper Closer

//Opens the Database
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}//DBAdapter Open Closer

//Closes the Database
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();       
} //DBAdapter Close Closer

//Insert a GamePlay into Database
public long insertTitle(String date, String casino, String game, String in, String out, String gain)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CASINO, casino);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GAME, game);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IN, in);
    initialValues.put(KEY_OUT, out);
    initialValues.put(KEY_GAIN, gain);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, initialValues);
} //Insert Title Closer

// Deletes a particular title
public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
} //Delete Title Closer

//Retrieves all titles
public Cursor getAllTitles()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]
            {
            KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_CASINO, KEY_GAME, KEY_IN, KEY_OUT, KEY_GAIN
            },null, null, null, null, null);        
} //Gets all titles closer

//Retrieves a particular Title
public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_CASINO, KEY_GAME, KEY_IN, KEY_OUT, KEY_GAIN},
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
} //getTitle Closer

//Updates a title
//  public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String KEY_DATE, String KEY_CASINO, String KEY_GAME, String KEY_IN, String KEY_OUT, String KEY_GAIN)
//  {
//      ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
//      args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
//      args.put(KEY_CASINO, casino);
//      args.put(KEY_GAME, game);
//      args.put(KEY_IN, in);
//      args.put(KEY_OUT, out);
//      args.put(KEY_GAIN, gain);
//      return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
//  } //Update Title Closer

} //Class Closer

-----------------------------
package kris.databasetester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DatabaseTesterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

  //---add 2 titles---
  db.open();
//      long id;
//      id = db.insertTitle("09/08/2012","The Sands","BlackJack", "400", "500", "100");
//     db.close();
    }
 }
 -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

it's telling you that `in` is not an allowable name for a column, which is because it's reserved for other uses in the SQL language.